# Using core functions from a custom namespace

Tags: clojure

I am trying to `refer` and alternately `qualify` basic core functions from a custom namespace, without luck:

```
cplay.core> (refer 'clojure.core)
nil
cplay.core> (clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core)
nil
cplay.core> (doc memoize)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: doc in this context, compiling:(/private/var/folders/0h/lzx021jx1rl95vhfxmcppmlc0000gn/T/form-init7998067657898575130.clj:1:1) 
cplay.core> (clojure.core/doc memoize)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: clojure.core/doc, compiling:(/private/var/folders/0h/lzx021jx1rl95vhfxmcppmlc0000gn/T/form-init7998067657898575130.clj:1:1)
```

I'm sure there is something simple here going on, can anyone advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `refer` `clojure.repl` to use `doc` macro.

```
user=> (ns xxx)
nil
xxx=> (clojure.repl/doc memoize)
-------------------------
clojure.core/memoize
([f])
  Returns a memoized version of a referentially transparent function. The
  memoized version of the function keeps a cache of the mapping from arguments
  to results and, when calls with the same arguments are repeated often, has
  higher performance at the expense of higher memory use.
nil
xxx=> (refer 'clojure.repl)
nil
xxx=> (doc memoize)
-------------------------
clojure.core/memoize
([f])
  Returns a memoized version of a referentially transparent function. The
  memoized version of the function keeps a cache of the mapping from arguments
  to results and, when calls with the same arguments are repeated often, has
  higher performance at the expense of higher memory use.
nil
```

Answer (score 1):

first `(use clojure.repl)` and then try `(doc memoize)`